# EmberJS RESTAdapter with extra parameters

Tags: asp.net, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have an emberjs application that uses an ASP .NET RESTfull web API to fetch data from the server. I use the ember RESTAdapter to connect to the web api, and this works great for these scenarios:

```
GET    products       //findAll
GET    products/{id}  //find
POST   products       //createRecord
PUT    products/{id}  //updateRecord
DELETE products/{id} //deleteRecord
```

But what if I encounter this scenario:

```
GET    products?categoryId=1
```

How can I call this method via Ember and process the result?

My ASP.NET REST API Controller

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
         private IOrderCaptureRepository _orderCapture;
         public ProductsController()
        {
            _orderCapture = new OrderCaptureRepository();
        }

        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            try
            {
                var result = Wrapper.WrapToEmber(_orderCapture.GetProducts());
                return Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return InternalServerError(e);
            }
        }

        public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = Wrapper.WrapToEmber(_orderCapture.GetProduct(id));
                if (result == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                return Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return InternalServerError();
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetProductsInCategory(int categoryId)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = Wrapper.WrapToEmber(_orderCapture.GetProducts(categoryId));
                return Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return InternalServerError();
            }
        }
    }
```

My Adapter:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
});

ApplicationAdapter.reopen({
    host: 'http://localhost:52703/',
    namespace: 'api/'
});


export default ApplicationAdapter;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting this question I discovered the [findQuery](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_findQuery) method on the RESTAdapter provided by ember.
This solves my problem!